# print a given number of characters or items per line to a textfile

Tags: python, printing, text-files

i would like to print a huge list of numbers to a textfile and each line should have 5 numbers in it. each number is 20 digits long.

below is the list of number (this huge list of numbers is called a1)

```
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08 1.6410391288046437544e-08 6.4151550079023113112e-08 9.9077814220256712144e-08 4.8228459783414887112e-08 1.6503915571969716123e-08 5.0759765831642425139e-08 1.4163943549368568877e-08 0.9171874262950143401e-08
2.2924892903408382299e-08 8.0910403085272639979e-08 0.1150909967310807486e-08 1.7800414806457459589e-08 9.9156327409347916878e-08 0.7474308272820071357e-08 4.8164050539957729897e-08 7.2570119501482690351e-08 5.5760621634989852061e-08 3.3409017307778332564e-08
4.7565190913441753115e-08 5.1557086343029653458e-08 6.3693801211606923532e-08 7.8897108738118126312e-08 9.4510334836961360301e-08 7.4880836459074272283e-08 4.9268327788150989424e-08 1.8466453757372403026e-08 6.2011855819003971679e-08 2.0783930984602632852e-08
0.9917554541229221025e-08 7.5224425124573985562e-08 2.6181377446191134266e-08 8.9009270149441469026e-08 7.7175189573912221707e-08 2.2170581996655944683e-08 3.2639560946849215485e-08 7.0901354279344938844e-08 5.5997044308008179085e-08 9.8907609461314007943e-08
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08
```

this is what i have so far.

```
with open('testfile5.txt','w') as testfile5:
    testfile5.write(a1)
    testfile5.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('testfile5.txt','w') as testfile5:
    text = ""
    for a in range(al):
        for i in range(5):
             text += str(al[(a*5)+i])
             testfile5.write(text)
        testfile5.write("/n")
    testfile5.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ddd.txt`:

```
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08 1.6410391288046437544e-08 6.4151550079023113112e-08 9.9077814220256712144e-08 4.8228459783414887112e-08 1.6503915571969716123e-08 5.0759765831642425139e-08 1.4163943549368568877e-08 0.9171874262950143401e-08
2.2924892903408382299e-08 8.0910403085272639979e-08 0.1150909967310807486e-08 1.7800414806457459589e-08 9.9156327409347916878e-08 0.7474308272820071357e-08 4.8164050539957729897e-08 7.2570119501482690351e-08 5.5760621634989852061e-08 3.3409017307778332564e-08
4.7565190913441753115e-08 5.1557086343029653458e-08 6.3693801211606923532e-08 7.8897108738118126312e-08 9.4510334836961360301e-08 7.4880836459074272283e-08 4.9268327788150989424e-08 1.8466453757372403026e-08 6.2011855819003971679e-08 2.0783930984602632852e-08
0.9917554541229221025e-08 7.5224425124573985562e-08 2.6181377446191134266e-08 8.9009270149441469026e-08 7.7175189573912221707e-08 2.2170581996655944683e-08 3.2639560946849215485e-08 7.0901354279344938844e-08 5.5997044308008179085e-08 9.8907609461314007943e-08
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08 6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08
```

Solution:

```
with open('ddd.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = []
    for line in f:
        nums.extend(line.split())

with open('eee.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(nums), 5):
        five_nums = ' '.join(nums[i:i + 5])
        f.write('{}\n'.format(five_nums))
```

`eee.txt`

```
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08
6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08 1.6410391288046437544e-08 6.4151550079023113112e-08 9.9077814220256712144e-08
4.8228459783414887112e-08 1.6503915571969716123e-08 5.0759765831642425139e-08 1.4163943549368568877e-08 0.9171874262950143401e-08
2.2924892903408382299e-08 8.0910403085272639979e-08 0.1150909967310807486e-08 1.7800414806457459589e-08 9.9156327409347916878e-08
0.7474308272820071357e-08 4.8164050539957729897e-08 7.2570119501482690351e-08 5.5760621634989852061e-08 3.3409017307778332564e-08
4.7565190913441753115e-08 5.1557086343029653458e-08 6.3693801211606923532e-08 7.8897108738118126312e-08 9.4510334836961360301e-08
7.4880836459074272283e-08 4.9268327788150989424e-08 1.8466453757372403026e-08 6.2011855819003971679e-08 2.0783930984602632852e-08
0.9917554541229221025e-08 7.5224425124573985562e-08 2.6181377446191134266e-08 8.9009270149441469026e-08 7.7175189573912221707e-08
2.2170581996655944683e-08 3.2639560946849215485e-08 7.0901354279344938844e-08 5.5997044308008179085e-08 9.8907609461314007943e-08
3.1948343452787551598e-08 8.2713170790435268456e-08 9.2997407466072783263e-08 2.2201974063356576525e-08 4.7184351703512537954e-08
6.4869237006439418830e-08 5.6105657006093290136e-08 2.5869788723656166592e-08 3.2336150408719792489e-08 1.3711755095387755690e-08
0.8466139114156927980e-08 8.6552265489125695952e-08
```

Comment: i don't think it works. what does the number 5 denote? i would assume number of stuff per line. 

i keep changing that and changing it does nothing.

the whole list just gets written up each time.

Comment: @tgmjack You said "each line should have 5 numbers in it", this code grabs five numbers at a time from `a1` and writes them to a line in `testfile5.txt`. [This is the output of the code above](https://bpaste.net/show/e9222a438b5f)

Comment: the numbers are all unchanged. 
I'm taking them from a file. there are 10 per line in the file. and when i try to print them to a new file, it still has 10 per line. heres my full code

def mi(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    rest= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, a1

bfirst,a1 = mi('ddd.txt')
with open('kkk.txt', 'w') as f:
     for i in range(0, len(a1), 5):
            five_nums = ' '.join(str(num) for num in a1[i:i + 5])
            f.write('{}\n'.format(five_nums))

Comment: @tgmjack Isn't this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assume a1 is list then try this:-

```
fl = open('testfile5.txt',"w") 
count = 0 
with open('ddd.txt','r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    line = line.strip().split()
    for i in range(5,len(line)+1,5):
        result = ''.join(str(line[count:i])) 
        fl.write(result+'\n') 
        count = i 

fl.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the help but, it does nothing. it just keeps the file empty 
(a1 comes from ddd.txt) 

def mi(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    rest= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, a1

bfirst,a1 = mi('ddd.txt')
fl = open('oh on.txt',"w")
count = 0

for i in range(5,len(a1)+1,5):
    result = ''.join(str(a1[count:i]))
    fl.write(result+'\n')
    count = i
fl.close()

Comment: @tgmjack modified my code as i was not aware that you are reading from file hence check now.